# ColdFusion pass enum to a Java method

Tags: java, enums, coldfusion, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using Azure Service Bus to receive the topic subscription messages and I need to pass the field of an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.receivemode?view=azure-dotnet)( `com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ReceiveMode.RECEIVEANDDELETE` ) to a method.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "tried using dollar format for enums"? If you mean use a `$`, that is only needed with inner classes. [ReceiveMode](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/ReceiveMode.java) isn't an inner class, so just create it as usual:

```
mode = createObject("java", "com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ReceiveMode");
```

Then pass the static field `RECEIVEANDDELETE` into the method

```
otherObject.someMethod( mode.RECEIVEANDDELETE );
```